# C# Algorithm to Tint a Color a Certain Percent

Tags: c#, algorithm, colors, system.drawing.color, tint

I have a color and I want get a tint of that color by a certain percent. So 100% is the color itself, 90% is a slightly lighter color, etc. Basically, it's like adding 10% of opacity to the color, if the color is on a white background. I need to convert the color into a hex HTML color value, so I don't want transparency.

Is there an algorithm to get a tint of the System.Drawing.Color RGB value?

Comment: Just an advice, don't use SetPixel/GetPixel, they are too slow. Use pointers instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep there are a lot of different ways to do this. One way would be to [convert from RGB to HSB](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/RgbToHsb.htm) (Hue, Saturation, Brightness) and then crank the brightness down some percentage.

Comment: I changed it to HSL, bumped the Lighting a percentage, then changed back to RGB. This works great. Here is a post on how to do this with C#, which is what I used. http://blogs.msdn.com/cjacks/archive/2006/04/12/575476.aspx